# Widehat with no argument

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols

I'm using `\widehat` to represent a mapping, so I would like to use it without arguments, for example,

```
Consider a mapping $\widehat{} : A \to B$, where $\widehat{a} = $...
```

Now the problem with this is that the spacing without any arguments is terrible, especially when I use it in text (e.g. `The mapping $\widehat{}$ above` renders terribly).

Is there any way I can make the spacing behave well? I tried doing things like `\widehat{~}` or `\mathop{\widehat{~}}` which made it a bit better, but it was still too close together in the text.

Comment: `$\widehat{\hspace{.7em}}$` to check what number to put in (may be .8em or .9em), put brackets around to have a sense of how much width are you giving to the symbol `$[\widehat{\hspace{.7em}}]$`.

Comment: Alternatively, use `\widehat{\phantom{X}}`, where `X` is your favourite character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for a blank argument, and if so, use `\phantom{x}` as the argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\let\svwidehat\widehat
\renewcommand\widehat[1]{\ifx\relax#1\relax\svwidehat{\phantom{x}}\else\svwidehat{#1}\fi}
\begin{document}
Consider a mapping $\widehat{} : A \to B$, where $\widehat{a} = $...
\end{document}
```

[image]